# Get one random row of large SQL table

Tags: sql

I want to use the StackExchange Data Explorer to get 1  random Java question that is not closed:

```
DECLARE @tagId int;

SELECT  @tagId = Id
FROM    Tags         
WHERE   TagName = 'java';

SELECT TOP 1 * FROM posts p join PostTags pt on pt.PostId = p.Id
WHERE pt.TagId = @tagId
AND p.PostTypeID = 1
AND p.ClosedDate IS NULL
Order by newid();
```

However, I get always the same result. Is this because the query is cached? Would that work without caching?

Comment: what is the result of this query? `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM posts p join PostTags pt on pt.PostId = p.Id
WHERE pt.TagId = 'java'
AND p.PostTypeID = 1
AND p.ClosedDate IS NULL`

Answer (score 1):

Even though we use the word random for these kinds of things, it remains the case that computers, by themselves cannot do anything randomly.

That's why they describe these computer functions as "pseudo-random".  Anytime you run the same thing multiple times, (unless it is dependent on some outside factor, like the current time or something) it will always generate the same result.

If you really want the thing to generate a different value everytime, then you must use a variant of the random function (most languages have this functionality), that takes a "seed" value as an input parameter, and use something like the current time (in ticks or milliseconds, or something like that) as the "seed".

Comment: Yes, can't I just use the current time as the seed for my random function?

Answer (score 1):

SQL is first applying the Top 1 clause and then doing the order by thats the reason you are getting the same result.

Try something like this:

```
DECLARE @tagId int;

SELECT  @tagId = Id
FROM    Tags         
WHERE   TagName = 'java';

;WITH CTE AS 
(SELECT * FROM posts p join PostTags pt on pt.PostId = p.Id
WHERE pt.TagId = @tagId
AND p.PostTypeID = 1
AND p.ClosedDate IS NULL
Order by newid();
) 

SELECT TOP 1 * FROM CTE
```

**OR** Try this:

```
DECLARE @tagId int;

SELECT  @tagId = Id
FROM    Tags         
WHERE   TagName = 'java';

SELECT TOP 1 * FROM 
(SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT * FROM posts p join PostTags pt on pt.PostId = p.Id
WHERE pt.TagId = @tagId
AND p.PostTypeID = 1
AND p.ClosedDate IS NULL
Order by newid();
) A
```

Comment: This gives me the following error: The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

Comment: SQL is first applying the Top 1 clause and then doing the order by thats the reason you are getting the same result. How about using a CTE or use TOP 100 PERCENT?

Comment: @FischerLudrian Updated the answer. Pl check now.